# How to calculate the number of operations that occur during the execution of a for loop?

Tags: algorithm, for-loop

I had an exam a couple of days ago and today the Instructor gave us the key answer of the exam.

One of the questions was

> ```
> for ( j = 9; j >= 1; j-- )
> ```
>
> Count the Number of operations

The result was 20.

Can anyone explain how he gets 20 operations from that?

Comment: Nice responses but not much effort from Maya.  This isn't a homework forum.

Comment: No it is not, but I'm a compulsive helper ;-).

Comment: @spoon16: That was a most unhelpful edit, IMHO. It makes the title hard to read on this site, hard to search for, and generally just a bad title. The question is repeated in full inside the text body. No need to squeeze it into the short (!!!) title.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

20 operations:

```
set j = 9
check if j(9) >= 1
set j to 8
check if j(8) >= 1
set j to 7
check if j(7) >= 1
set j to 6
check if j(6) >= 1
set j to 5
check if j(5) >= 1
set j to 4
check if j(4) >= 1
set j to 3
check if j(3) >= 1
set j to 2
check if j(2) >= 1
set j to 1
check if j(1)>=1
set j to 0
check if j(0)>=1
```

for( j=n ; j>=0 ; j-- )

Ok, you start with two operations:

- (j=n)
- check (j>=0).

For all n<0 it stops there.

If n=0, you get an aditional:

- j--
- check (j>=0).

For n=1, you get another set of those.

So the number of operations is 2 for n<0 and 2n+4 for n>=0.

These things are not that hard. You just need to think like a computer and carefully note any change to the state (set of variables).

Comment: Actually, this is a very explanation. :)

Comment: this is great thanx a lot
can you explaine in the same this
 for(  j=n  ;  j>=0  ;  j-- )

for(  j=1  ;  j<10  ;  j++ )

Comment: Hey Maya, now that you've been taught how to fish maybe it's time to try your hand at it.  Follow the methodology and see what you get.

Comment: I did it right for the for( j=1 ; j<10 ; j++ )
but its not working with the for( j=n ; j>=0 ; j-- )

Comment: C'mon, Maya.  Same principles.  And the contraction for "it is" is "it's".

Comment: The contraction for "I am" is "I'm".

Comment: @chaos, duffymo, you are mean ;-).

Comment: Gamecat should i give n a value and then try or what should i do

Comment: Nope, if this is an educational forum Maya should be as grateful for grammar help as she is for programming.  Maya won't be able to bring Gamecat into her next exam, so she'd better learn how to do this herself.  Nothing "mean" about that, just a fact.

Comment: @duffymo, you are right. The remark about "mean" was on the grammar remarks. Hence the ;-).

Answer (score 3):

Well, in the first iteration, `j` is set to `9`. After that, each iteration basically executes the same two instructions:

- first, test whether `j >= 1`, and
- second, decrement `j` (`j--`).

This is done nine times (from `9` inclusively to `0` inclusively). In the very last iteration, we test again whether `j >= 1` and since this is false, we exit the loop. We therefore get 1 + 9 * 2 + 1 = 20 iterations.

Answer (score 0):

What value did you write down?  Just curious.

Let's count them together, maya:

```
for (j = 9; j >= 1; j--)
```

one for assigning 9 to j = 1;
one comparison of the current value of j to 1 for each iteration of the loop = 10;
one decrement of j for each iteration of the loop except the last one = 9;

1 + 10 + 9 = 20 in my book.

Answer (score 0):

You have 1 assignment (j=9). The "j--" operation will be run 9 times; the conditional check "j>=1" will be run 10 times (every iteration you ask the question "is j>=1"), the last will fail. So you have 1 + 9 + 10 = 20.

Your instructor is very, very bad if he is so mean as to not offer to help. This is one of those questions you either get or don't. The instructor should help. :)

Comment: I'd want more context before I decided that the instructor was "mean" or "bad".

Comment: Well, it's not an absolute judgment. If you use logic, I used a "conditional" which is to say "IF he is to be so mean as to not offer help THEN he is very, very bad." Just basic logic 101. :)  I see profs like this a lot, it's infuriating. However, if the OP is wrong then no harm, no foul. :)